# ¿Cómo actualizar aquellas partes de un proyecto en donde se realizaron los cambios, sin publicar todo el proyecto?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy iniciando el mundo de la programación, estoy trabajando con un proyecto (Aplicación web ASP.NET de Visual Studio) que se modifica constantemente, añadiendo noticias, archivos, imágenes, etc., y dada esa situación y para no estar borrando y publicando de nueva cuenta todo el proyecto, como le puedo hacer para que sólo se actualicen aquellas partes donde se realizaron los cambios, sin tener que subir todo el proyecto???

Comment: Al momento de publicar con visual studio, si tienes el servidor configurado. solo publicara los archivos agregados o que tuvieron cambios

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos, imágenes y también las Vistas, las puedes publicar independientemente con **botón derecho** del ratón sobre el archivo y -> **`Publicar <elemento>`**.

Si las modificaciones son de código de Servidor, clases, Controladores, etc. Te recomiendo compiles el proyecto y lo **publiques todo**.

En lo que respecta a borrar toda la publicación y volverla a publicar, por defecto, Visual Studio a la hora de publicar, solo te sube al servidor los archivos que **han sido modificados** y los **nuevos**.

Todo esto que te digo, es para Visual Studio 2017 y 2019.